# No matching constructor for initialization of 'type'

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-construction, constructor, copy-constructor

I trying to fix my vector not able to push_back problem but i get this error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:1456:36:
>   No matching constructor for initialization of 'Point'

here is my code

Class

```
class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Uint8 r;
    Uint8 g;
    Uint8 b;
    Point(int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b) : x(x), y(y), r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
    Point& operator=(Point const &np){
        x=np.x;
        y=np.y;
        r=np.r;
        g=np.g;
        b=np.b;
        return *this;
    }
    Point(const Point& point);
    ;
};
```

Line maybe cause error:

```
std::vector<Point> temp(10);
```

and this also not working:

```
std::vector<Point> temp;
```

Please help

here is more error message hope this help:

> /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Source/Week3_T.cpp:8:10:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Source/Week3_T.cpp:8:
>
> /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Headers/Week3_T.h:3:10:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Headers/Week3_T.h:3:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/vector:265:10:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:265:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:10:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/algorithm:627:10:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:627:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/vector:925:25:
>   In instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::allocator_traits
>
> > ::construct' requested here
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/vector:1028:9:
>   In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector >::__construct_at_end' requested here
>
> /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Source/Week3_T.cpp:466:19:
>   In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector >::vector' requested here
>
> /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Headers/Week3_T.h:15:5:
>   Candidate constructor not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 0 were
>   provided
>
> /Users/sum/Documents/3407ICT_Starter_Kit_v8/ProjectOSX/Headers/Week3_T.h:24:5:
>   Candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'point',
>   but no arguments were provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard library, certain containers "fill in" values using the default constructor when the value is not given explicitly. `vector<Point> temp(10)` initializes the vector with 10 elements, which are filled with the default-constructed value of your type. But when you have defined this constructor:

`Point(int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b) : x(x), y(y), r(r), g(g), b(b)`
the compiler will not implicitly define a default constructor, so no constructor is available now. You can fix the compiler error by defining another constructor:

```
Point(){}
```

Comment: Thanks, its work, not sure if i submit this code to a Windows machine still work or not? Thanks anyway, ng goi sai